# subarray of 2D array to NULL

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d

I have the following array in C++:

```
int arr[3][2] = { 
                 {1, 2}, 
                 {3, 4}, 
                 {5, 6} 
                };
```

And I want to implement data like this:

```
arr[1] = NULL;
```

But this doesn't work. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: simplify array verification

Comment: It isn't entirely clear *what* you're trying to do. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve, because from the looks of it you need a pointer array; not an array of arrays.

Comment: A fixed-size array cannot be NULL